# Can embedded software be patented in the EU?

Tags: european-union, patents

I know that no software can be patented in Europe. But what if I use software in an electronic board, and introduce that hardware?  Can that be patented?

Comment: You'll probably have better luck with this question at http://patents.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

Software cannot be patented although it does have copyright.

Hardware can be the subject of a patent, however, that would not cover any software aspects such as the programming built into a PROM.

While it is possible to render any software into an integrated circuit, practically, anything simple enough to make this feasible is probably too simple to patent.